# Combining two dataframes into 1 (only taking certain columns!)

Tags: python, pandas

This is probably easy, but I have the following data:

In data frame 1:

```
ID data data2
0     9  66 
1     5  664
```

In data frame 2:

```
ID data data6
2     7  tt
3     6  xtt
```

I want a data frame with the following for (only taking the first 2 columns from the above examples)

```
ID data
0     9     
1     5     
2     7
3     6
```

I've tried using the append method, but I get a cross join (i.e. cartesian product).

Just looking for the right way to do this?

Comment: `pd.concat([df1[['ID', 'data']], df2[['ID', 'data']]])`?

Answer (score 0):

```
pd.concat([df1[['ID', 'data']], df2[['ID', 'data']]])
```

solved - Thanks Chris